# What is the difference between baseline, first baseline, and last baseline in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The CSS property `align-items` can be set to `baseline`, `first baseline`, and `last baseline` ([CSS Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)). What are the differences between these values?

```css
.flex-container {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item1 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.item2 {
  align-self: baseline;
}

.item3 {
  align-self: first baseline;
}

.item4 {
  align-self: last baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item1">flex-start</div>
  <div class="flex-item item2">baseline</div>
  <div class="flex-item item3">first baseline</div>
  <div class="flex-item item4">last baseline</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`first baseline` and `baseline` are synonyms.

"First" and "last" refer to the line boxes within the flex items. The best way to understand is with an example:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}
.first {
  align-items: first baseline;
}
.last {
  align-items: last baseline;
}
div {
  flex: 1;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

hr {
  width: 80%;
}

/* to depict where the relevant baseline is */
section .baseline-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
.first .baseline-indicator {
  top: 36px;
}
.last .baseline-indicator {
  top: 173px;
}
```

```html
<section class="first">
  <div>alpha<br>beta<br>gamma</div>
  <div>delta<br>epsilon<br>zeta<br>eta</div>
  <div>iota</div>
  <div class="baseline-indicator"></div>
</section>
<hr>
<section class="last">
  <div>alpha<br>beta<br>gamma</div>
  <div>delta<br>epsilon<br>zeta<br>eta</div>
  <div>iota</div>
  <div class="baseline-indicator"></div>
</section>
```

We can see from the red lines that with `first baseline`, the baselines of the first text rows (i.e. "alpha", "delta", "iota") are aligned.

And with `last baseline`, the baselines of the last text rows (i.e. "gamma", "eta", "iota") are aligned.